# Angular Materials "mat-slide-toggle" override

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I am new to the use of anugular materials.
I would like overloaded ......
I want to change the color of the Google when it is off but I don't know how to do it.
Thanks for your help.
This is my code Html:

```
<form>
    <mat-slide-toggle class="livre-toggle" color="primary" [checked]="isChecked"
        (change)="toggleChanged($event, label)" translate>
        {{label | translate}}
    </mat-slide-toggle>
</form>
```

### In my SCSS I need to change the color of toggle Thanks.

Comment: use [class]="myClass" or multiple class separate by space with a variable instead of a string and affect the good class into myClass in your toggleChanged function, use a class with a different color of course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following as a quick fix:

```
::ng-deep {
    mat-slide-toggle {
        .mat-slide-toggle-bar {
            background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6); // your bar color here
            .mat-slide-toggle-thumb {
                background-color: #000; // your slide thumb color here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer.
So I would not need to use the name at the level of the class attribute.

`class="livre-toggle"`

Comment: @koko the main thing is to add "**::ng-deep**", under that u can use your class if u want or directly u can use the tag name like i have used.